Create a loop to copy data from one workbook to another then copy the results back into the original workbook
I am trying to create a loop to copy data from an inputs worksheet on one workbook, open a template workbook, enter the data, then copy the results back into an outputs worksheet, and Save As the template workbook with a unique identifier (here titled Unit1_). Then continue to the next row on the inputs worksheet until there is no more data.
Bonus points if you can make the unique identifier dynamic and save it all in a unique folder.
Sub CopyOverNoHarvMAINT()

Dim NoHarv_Maint As String
Dim openNoHarv_Maint As String
Dim filePath As String
Dim fileName1 As String    

openNoHarv_Maint = "C:\Users\Desktop\Carbon Calc\NoHarvest_Maintenance.xlsx"
filePath = "C:\Users\Desktop\Carbon Calc\"
NoHarv_Maint = "NoHarvest_Maintenance.xlsx"
fileName1 = "Unit1_"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Workbooks.Open (openNoHarv_Maint)
    Windows(NoHarv_Maint).Activate
    Range("C3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='[CC input.xlsm]Inputs'!R5C2"
    Range("C5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='[CC input.xlsm]Inputs'!R5C3"
    Range("C6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='[CC input.xlsm]Inputs'!R5C4"
    Range("C7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='[CC input.xlsm]Inputs'!R5C5"
    
    Range("H10").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("CC input.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Outputs").Select
    Range("B5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    Windows(NoHarv_Maint).Activate
    Range("R10").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("CC input.xlsm").Activate
    Range("C5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    Windows(NoHarv_Maint).Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=filePath & fileName1 & NoHarv_Maint
    ActiveWindow.Close

I would go to row 6 on the input worksheet next and open up the template again and to be saved as Unit2_.
Appreciate the help!

You're asking too much but sharing too little. Nevertheless, feel free to download a copy of my working file from my Google Drive to at least get you started.

Side note: in general, you want to avoid using Select in your code

@VBasic2008 I will take a look at what you made and see if I can incorporate it.

@cybernetic.nomad I will take this into account. I used to do a bit of VBA work, just getting back into it. Appreciate the Insite!

This is the adjusted code to step through the range of data.
Sub CopyOverNoHarvMAINT()

    Dim NoHarv_Maint As String
    Dim openNoHarv_Maint As String
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim fileName1 As String
    openNoHarv_Maint = "C:\Users\Desktop\Carbon Calc\NoHarvest_Maintenance.xlsx"
    filePath = "C:\Users\Desktop\Carbon Calc\"
    NoHarv_Maint = "NoHarvest_Maintenance.xlsx"
    'fileName1 = "Unit1_"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    filenamecounter = 1
    fileName1 = "Unit"
    lastrow = Workbooks("CC input.xlsm").Worksheets("Inputs").Range("B5").End(xlDown).Row
    For i = 5 To lastrow
        Workbooks.Open (openNoHarv_Maint)
        Windows(NoHarv_Maint).Activate
        Range("C3").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='[CC input.xlsm]Inputs'!R" & i & "C2"
        Range("C5").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='[CC input.xlsm]Inputs'!R" & i & "C3"
        Range("C6").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='[CC input.xlsm]Inputs'!R" & i & "C4"
        Range("C7").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='[CC input.xlsm]Inputs'!R" & i & "C5"
        Range("H10").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("CC input.xlsm").Activate
        Sheets("Outputs").Select
        Range("B" & i).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Windows(NoHarv_Maint).Activate
        Range("R10").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("CC input.xlsm").Activate
        Range("C" & i).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Windows(NoHarv_Maint).Activate
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=filePath & fileName1 & filenamecounter & "_" & NoHarv_Maint
        ActiveWindow.Close
        filenamecounter = filenamecounter + 1
    Next i

End Sub
    


